# Javascript & Discord.js - Repeating something the length of an array

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was wondering how to repeat something as many times as there are things in an array.

This is what I tried, but it didn't work:

`var channels = [ '407711330943107072' ]`

```
for (let i in channels.length) {
   console.log(channels[i - 1])
       var channel = client.channels.get(channels[i - 1])
       channel.setTopic(description)
      }
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working, or a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: I think you want `for (let i in channels)`. Also- change i-1 to i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```
for (const channelId of channels) {
   console.log(channelId);
   const channel = client.channels.get(channelId);
   channel.setTopic(description);
}
```

I guess yours wasn't working because you were trying to iterate over `channels.length`, which is a number, and is not iterable.

See [Iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol).

Answer (score 0):

```js
let channels = ['example_value', 'second_value']

for (let i in channels) {
   console.log(channels[i])
   //do stuff
}
```

You were making a slight mistake with your looping. Doing `for let i in array` will go through each element. You also want to directly access the values by using `i` instead of `i-1`